# I am able to write data to Azure table storage, but I'm not able to read from table

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-table-storage

I am using Nodejs - TS Express server. I am trying to read the data from the table called tracker which also has the partition name as tracker. I am able to write to the table with no issues, but when I'm trying to use listEntities or getEntities, I'm getting
`The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.`
Here is the code what I am using to get the list. I tried using the sas token as well, it too had same problem.

```
import { AzureNamedKeyCredential, TableClient, TableServiceClient, odata , AzureSASCredential, generateTableSas } from "@azure/data-tables";
import { Mail, MailEntity } from "../models/mail";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

const accountName = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const accountKey = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";
const tablesUrl = process.env.TABLES_URL || "";
const tableName = process.env.TABLE_NAME || "";
const sas_token = process.env.SAS_TOKEN || "";

const creds = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)

const client = new TableClient(tablesUrl, tableName, creds);


client.listEntities({
    queryOptions: { filter: odata`PartitionKey eq tracker` }
  }).next().then((result)=>{
    result.value.entities.forEach((res:MailEntity)=>{
        console.log(res)
    })
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error.message)
    console.log("Error listing all entities")
  })
```

We tried a sample project in Springboot, its working just fine with the same credentials. I have also read some other people facing similar issue but they either didnt provide the solution or those solution did not work.

Comment: Please try by changing your query from `PartitionKey eq tracker` to `PartitionKey eq 'tracker'`.

Comment: still error is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
I have been using Account name, Account key, SaS token etc in various combination, Nothing was working for me. But when I used the connection string
like

`const client = TableClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, tableName)`

its working as intended. But why I was able to write to DB but not read from DB still remains a mystery when I was using the Account name + Account Key combination

Answer (score 0):

Using this [Reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/tables/data-tables/samples/v12/typescript/src/queryEntities.ts) I am able to read the details in the Azure Storage Table.  The table URL will be `https://StorageaccountName.table.core.windows.net`.

- Sample example to get the list from Azure Storage Table.

**Code:**

```js
import { TableClient } from "@azure/data-tables";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

const tablesUrl = process.env["TABLES_URL"] || "";
const sasToken = process.env["SAS_TOKEN"] || " ";

async function listAllEntities() {
  console.log("== List All Entities Sample ==");

  const tableName = `sampath123`;

  const client = new TableClient(`${tablesUrl}${sasToken}`, tableName);

  const listResults = client.listEntities();

  for await (const entity of listResults) {
    console.log(`PartitionKey: ${entity.partitionKey}, RowKey: ${entity.rowKey}`);
    
    // Iterate through properties and log key-value pairs
    for (const propName of Object.keys(entity)) {
      if (propName !== 'partitionKey' && propName !== 'rowKey') {
        console.log(`${propName}: ${entity[propName]}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

export async function main() {
  await listAllEntities();
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.error("The sample encountered an error:", err);
});
```

**Azure:**

[image]

**Local Output:**

[image]